# the only call to server is an UnknownHostException

Tags: android, web-services, android-emulator

```
try {
    InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.google.com");
    Log.e("InetAddress", "InetAddress");
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

It gives an `unknownHostException`. That is the onl thing that the app does with the server. Why is that happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Thank you for finally including code, but you need to edit this information into your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12903644/1267661) on this subject (as this is the third time you have asked). Please consult the [faq] on acceptable ways to get more attention to an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have permissions set up for the device to use the internet?

[What permission do I need to access Internet from an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)

Comment: The question that i have is do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest that gives the app permission to use the internet.