# MainActivity can't find ListView with id of android.R.id.list, but it's there

Tags: android

I was following [**this tutorial**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

I've modified it to my app's needs, such as no **CRUD** functionality and no main menu - I just want to list all the items during the main activity that gets executed when the app is launched.

Code seems to have no errors, but running it gives me: `Unfortunately, MyFirstApp has stopped` in the VM.

**LogCat** gives me this:

> E/AndroidRuntime(910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstproject/com.example.myfirstproject.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

What do? I've checked my .xml layouts and made the changes, but the app still crashes.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstproject;

//imports

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> carsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_cars = "http://localhost/webservice/get_all_cars.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CARS = "cars";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray cars = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        carsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllcars().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllcars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading cars. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_cars, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All cars: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    cars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = cars.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String title = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        carsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("No cars found");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, carsList,
                            android.R.id.list, new String[] {TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.title });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml** (layout for the mainactivity with listview):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml** (layout for individual list items):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at how they define the layout in the ListActivity documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Your ListView Id is `android:id="@+id/list"` and it needs to be `android:id="@android:id/list"`

additionally, your ListAdapter is going to crash

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, carsList,
                            android.R.id.list, new String[] {TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.title });
```

You are telling the adapter to use the android ListView as the Item view..
You should be passing in your list_item.xml ID for this and using the proper TextView ID (name)

ex:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, carsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.name});
```

Comment: Seems to get to the "Loading cars...Please wait" dialog, but after some time it crashes again. LogCat gives the following: `E/Buffer Error(999): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
E/JSON Parser(999): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
E/AndroidRuntime(999): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(999): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`. Sorry, I'm very new to this and the error doesn't seem to tell me much like the previous did besides that there's some NullPointerException somewhere

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your JSON parsing you are getting a null pointer. In the stack trace it should point to the line in your code where its crashing

Comment: Looks like it's this line: `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_cars, "GET", params);`, therefore it implies that it doesn't get the list of cars from my PHP webservice(running on wamp)? Why wouldn't it work? If I go straight to the `url_all_cars` path in any web browser I get the JSON list generated properly.

Comment: Do you have the internet permission set in your apps manifest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application

Comment: Just did. Same problem on the same line. But I'm using a localhost(MySQL, WAMP on my computer) so do I need that permission?

Comment: Also, this line sets the error off: `Log.d("All Cars: ", json.toString());`

Comment: please don't use the comments to ask additional questions; new questions should be created as a new question...

Answer (score 2):

In your `activity_main.xml` use `android:id="@android:id/list"` and not `android:id="@+id/list"` and it should work.

For now the ID of your ListView is `yourapplicationpackage.R.id.list`.

Answer (score 2):

use `android:id="@android:id/list"` while assigning the id in xml.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the id of the ListView **must** be `@android:id/list` to reference the required `android.R.id.list` per the [ListActivity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

In contrast, your id of `@+id/list` creates a new id `com.example.myfirstproject.R.id.list`.

Answer (score 0):

It is old post but for others who faced same problem here is my solution:

If you are make sure, the ID of the List View or any other object you created is existed in layout - To make sure go head to gen sources, check the name of the id in R.java file. If it is not there, then you didn't create any item. - Then, In Java Code make sure android.R is not in the import list. If so rid off. Then manually add your package R.java 
   import com.yourpackagename.R;
Now you are able to add our item into Java Code: exp: 
   ListView lvitems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nameofit);

I don't recommend that Project>Clean in these situations, you could easily lose your generated R.java file.

Comment: Losing a generated file, so what ?