# Server/Client Android program doesn't work on real android device

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server, wifi

I'm making a Server/Client program that sends and receives data between them.
The program is working perfectly on the emulator, but when testing it on a real android device through WIFI it can't connect to the server.

Server Side

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(44444);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Client Side

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 44444);
```

The problem isn't in sending data, it's in the connection establishment. That Android phone doesn't see the server side !

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Nope. The program opens normally but can't connect.

Comment: Yes but did you debug it? You must have some kind of stacktrace somewhere...

Comment: Have you set permission in Android to Allow using internet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application

Comment: Yup
And it works fine on emulator, but doesn't on real device !

Comment: How about your firewall, have you turn it off? (on port 44444 as your code?)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a constructor, which expects a string *hostname*. However, you are providing an internet address. You have to use another [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29), which accepts an address as a parameter.

Try the following code on the client side:

```
Socket socket = new Socket (InetAddress.getByName ("192.168.1.2"), 44444);
```

Comment: Error: the constructor Socket(InetAddress[], int) is undefined !

Comment: Are you sure you changed `getAllByName` to `getByName`? See the link in my post. It shows the `Socket(InetAddress, int)` is defined and documented as of API level 1.

Comment: Yeah i did it, my code now is: Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"), 44444);

Comment: And the error is the same? Does the error log show the error in the same place? Did you paste my code in multiple files? Paste the new error.

Comment: There is no error. The server still running and the client running but when i'm trying to connect nothing happens

Comment: Hmmm, don't really know if relevant, but as a last resort, could you try `Socket socket = new Socket (InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{(byte)192, (byte)168, 1, 2}), 44444);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server is visibile to your smartphone?...You could try to connect a pc to the WIFI and use telnet ip port and verify if you can reach the server.

Comment: How can i make sure that server is visible to smartphone ?

Comment: if you have pc you can connect it to the WIFI (the same used by your smartphone) and then with a tcp client you can try to connect to your server.

Answer (score 0):

the android devices can not detect the ad-hoc network of windows 
you have to first make your PC hotspot by doing this :

step 1: open CMD (admin privileged) and run following command 
netsh wlan hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD

this will make wifi , a hotspot
now run this to start wifi hotspot:
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

and to stop hotspot run this command :
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your network.
Please make sure that the real android device and the your server(`192.168.1.2`) are in the same network.

If those are in the same network only then you can communicate with the server from yourclient

Comment: Try to install Ping app from android play store and make sure that you are being able to communicate to the port 44444 from your device https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping

Comment: I think your port 44444 is not open for the device.

Comment: There is an option in the spinner of the application's Home Page called "Check Port Range".Select it and give your port number you want to check.

Comment: When i checked if the port 44444 is open or not it connects on it and told me that it is opened but the program still can't connect to the server !