# How to debug an app that crashes instantly?

Tags: android

This is my ActivityMain

```
package com.quinnco.facebookmessagefeed;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   WebView webview;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Feed);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/home");
    WebSettings websettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    WebView myWebView_Chat = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Chat);
    myWebView_Chat.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/messages");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is my Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.quinnco.facebookmessagefeed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.quinnco.facebookmessagefeed.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

All my apps I make won't run, they crash instantly on my phone and my emulator. I checked over all my code, I'm new to it.

Comment: can you post your logcat please.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try with a simple app first.  Crash can happen due to many reasons.  A typical case is your main_activity.xml contains errors.  I assume R.main.menu is also an xml file for you.  Check that part as well.

If all programs are crashing, then you start from very basic.  Write a very simple "Hello world" program first.  Make sure it doesn't crash.  Then build upon it step by step, each time making sure, no crash happens.

Comment: I did that with this as well

Comment: Thank you that worked wonderfully I relooked at a succsessful app and saw a mistake in this it was my activity_main file

Comment: That's a horrible answer. If your xml contains errors, the app won't be built, so it won't run, and can't crash. Rather than starting over with a "simple" program each time your app crashes, as the answer suggests, learn how to use your debugging tools: The logcat tells you *exactly* where the crash occurred. Then fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I see no settings for [permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) in your manifest. This tends to cause applications to crash instead of exiting gracefully. Try adding the [INTERNET permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application) to your manifest and see if it helps.

Comment: i have my permissons to go <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> thats what i use under the uses sdk