# android-ndk SOCK_RAW permissions

Tags: android, linux, networking, android-ndk

I have so task that make android device talk to some device that uses ethernet directly. On linux I can use

```
setcap CAP_NET_RAW+ep /path/to/your/program-file
```

to setup permissions.

But I can't find how to make it under android.

I have rooted device and I can edit ueventrc.d

My program will run only on my device and I can customize platform.

I use NDK-r8.

Comment: You also need the `INTERNET` permission in your app manifest.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/.

Comment: I used INTERNET permission, but if you using SOCK_RAW you have to use root permissions