# jReddit Java Exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, jreddit

I'm using this [java wrapper](https://github.com/jReddit/jReddit) for the Reddit API. Basically, I'm developing an android reddit app. Here is my `MainActivity.java` code:

```
package com.example.reddit;

import im.goel.jreddit.submissions.Submission;
import im.goel.jreddit.submissions.Submissions;
import im.goel.jreddit.user.User;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView username;
    private TextView password;
    private User reddit;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usern = username.getText().toString();
                String passw = password.getText().toString();

                reddit = new User(usern, passw);
                try {
                    reddit.connect();

                    List<Submission> submissions = Submissions.getSubmissions(
                            "cfb",
                            Submissions.Popularity.HOT,
                            Submissions.Page.FRONTPAGE,
                            reddit);

                    for(Submission submission: submissions) {
                        System.out.println(submission);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I ran this in debug mode and when it executes the line `reddit.connect();` it throws an exception. Here's what the logcat says:

```
12-01 14:54:03.670: W/ActivityThread(6095): Application com.example.reddit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-01 14:54:03.670: I/System.out(6095): Sending WAIT chunk
12-01 14:54:03.690: I/dalvikvm(6095): Debugger is active
12-01 14:54:03.870: I/System.out(6095): Debugger has connected
12-01 14:54:03.880: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:04.080: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:04.280: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:04.480: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:04.680: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:04.880: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:05.080: I/System.out(6095): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:54:05.290: I/System.out(6095): debugger has settled (1380)
12-01 14:54:05.630: D/PhoneWindow(6095): DebugMonitor class=com.example.reddit.MainActivity focus=true
12-01 14:54:40.570: W/System.err(6095): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
12-01 14:54:40.590: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
12-01 14:54:40.590: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:187)
12-01 14:54:40.600: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
12-01 14:54:40.600: W/System.err(6095):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:872)
12-01 14:54:40.610: W/System.err(6095):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1019)
12-01 14:54:40.610: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
12-01 14:54:40.620: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
12-01 14:54:40.620: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:395)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.sendRequest(HttpURLConnection.java:1224)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnection.java:1563)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doRequest(HttpURLConnection.java:1556)
12-01 14:54:40.630: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1145)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnection.java:262)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at im.goel.jreddit.utils.Utils.post(Utils.java:49)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at im.goel.jreddit.user.User.hashCookiePair(User.java:266)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at im.goel.jreddit.user.User.connect(User.java:45)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at com.example.reddit.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6661)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
12-01 14:54:40.640: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2068)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1708)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 14:54:40.650: W/System.err(6095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 14:54:40.660: W/System.err(6095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
12-01 14:54:40.660: W/System.err(6095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:54:40.660: W/System.err(6095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-01 14:54:40.660: W/System.err(6095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-01 14:54:40.660: W/System.err(6095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-01 14:54:40.660: W/System.err(6095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 14:55:37.200: W/ActivityThread(6128): Application com.example.reddit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-01 14:55:37.210: I/System.out(6128): Sending WAIT chunk
12-01 14:55:37.210: I/dalvikvm(6128): Debugger is active
12-01 14:55:37.410: I/System.out(6128): Debugger has connected
12-01 14:55:37.410: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:37.610: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:37.810: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:38.010: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:38.210: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:38.410: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:38.610: I/System.out(6128): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:55:38.820: I/System.out(6128): debugger has settled (1437)
12-01 14:55:39.150: D/PhoneWindow(6128): DebugMonitor class=com.example.reddit.MainActivity focus=true
12-01 14:55:56.620: W/System.err(6128): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:187)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:872)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1019)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
12-01 14:55:56.630: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1272)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at im.goel.jreddit.utils.Utils.get(Utils.java:99)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at im.goel.jreddit.submissions.Submissions.getSubmissions(Submissions.java:62)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at com.example.reddit.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6661)
12-01 14:55:56.640: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2068)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
12-01 14:55:56.650: W/System.err(6128):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1708)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-01 14:55:56.660: W/System.err(6128):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 14:58:00.410: W/ActivityThread(6166): Application com.example.reddit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-01 14:58:00.410: I/System.out(6166): Sending WAIT chunk
12-01 14:58:00.420: I/dalvikvm(6166): Debugger is active
12-01 14:58:00.620: I/System.out(6166): Debugger has connected
12-01 14:58:00.620: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:00.820: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:01.020: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:01.220: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:01.420: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:01.620: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:01.820: I/System.out(6166): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 14:58:02.030: I/System.out(6166): debugger has settled (1434)
12-01 14:58:02.380: D/PhoneWindow(6166): DebugMonitor class=com.example.reddit.MainActivity focus=true
```

What is this `java.net.SocketException` and how do I fix it?

Comment: `12-01 14:54:40.570: W/System.err(6095): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (**maybe missing INTERNET permission**)`. Check your internet connection with your android phone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application does this help?

Comment: @tintinmj omg....i've fixed a problem similar to this with this before...i don't know why i didn't think of that. Ya it worked now, thanks a lot. You can post the answer, i'll check it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the Log `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)`. And a little bit of googling I found out

Add the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Thanks to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application).