# How to know the reachable of any url address?

Tags: android

I wrote the following method to know the reachable of url.

```
public boolean isMyURLReachable(String url){
    boolean reachable = false;
    try {
        reachable = InetAddress.getByName(url).isReachable(2000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return reachable;
}
```

and I call it like that.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        boolean reachable = isMyURLReachable("www.google.com");
        if(reachable)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reachable", 500).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unreachable", 500).show();
    }
});
```

But android.os.NetworkMainThreadException occur, do I need anything to put in my androidmanifest.xml file or my idea is being wrong?

Comment: you need the internet permission for sure.

Comment: yes, you probably have to add internet access permission to your AndroidManifest.xml. check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)

Comment: Did you read the exception and tried to google it?

Comment: I've access permissions at my manifest.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkMainThreadException` is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

Please try to perform that in an `AysncTask` or another thread.

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: @CristyYG you are welcome :) Please accept the answer if that solved your problem and other guys can see that if they have the same problem ;)

Comment: No more exception this time.., but result is not correct. Anyhow.., you answer is the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following inner class.

```
class URLCheckTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        boolean reachable = false;
        try {
            reachable = InetAddress.getByName(url[0]).isReachable(7000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(reachable)
            return "1";
        else
            return "0";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result.equals("1"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "reachable", 500).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unreachable", 500).show();
    }

}
```

and call it from onClick() method.

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new URLCheckTask().execute("www.google.com");
        }
    });
```

No exception occur this time. But...., the result is not correct even though I can call it from emulator's browser, it always show me unreachable.