# Picasso not loading URL into image

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I had used [Picasso  library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) in a `ListView`  multiple times and worked fine, But now i can't use it for easy things like this sample project.

Please help

```
package com.example.picasso_image;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView _imageview = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(_imageview);

  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.picasso_image.MainActivity"
   tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application

Comment: Any logcat relevant information?

Comment: @petey Thank you. I forgot the INTERNET permission

Comment: @user3269815   :),  happens to the best of us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The above must be places in the correct AndroidManifest.xml file.

Also, make sure your device is connected to a network and is not in airplane mode.