# Couldn't parse the HTML tags from live site in android

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

We are working on a power shut down app in android domain for a particular region.so we need the live update details from the URL.so we need to get the HTML tags from the live site.we got nothing.

For example in this app we get a title from the live URL and put it in a text view
the code comes here.We are using JSOUP to get the values.

```
package com.example.poweralert.app;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;



public class PrimaryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RadioGroup radioOptionGroup;
private RadioButton radiooptiobtn;
private Button btnDisplay;



/*public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("locate.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_primary);
    String title=null;
    Document document;
    try {
        document= Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
        title=document.title();
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(title);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("tag","document");

    }

    /*List<String> formList= new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jSONObject.getJSONArray("Manali");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (jo_inside.has("location")) {
                formList.add(jo_inside.getString("location"));
            }
        }



        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, formList));


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndis);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




        }
    });
}
```

}

how to show the live URL site title in text view.the above code shows nothing.

myHtml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="html text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

also got this in log cat when running the app

```
04-03 12:29:11.123  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize : 0
04-03 12:29:11.124  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get new systemTid : 26083
04-03 12:29:11.124  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-03 12:29:11.127  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ prepping for JDWP over ADB
04-03 12:29:11.127  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ ADB transport startup
04-03 12:29:11.127  26083-26086/com.example.ipower.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Elevating priority from 0 to -8
04-03 12:29:11.127  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ JDWP: thread running
04-03 12:29:11.130  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ acceptConnection
04-03 12:29:11.130  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
04-03 12:29:11.143  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ received file descriptor 40 from ADB
04-03 12:29:11.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get thread init done
04-03 12:29:11.148  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
04-03 12:29:11.148  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
04-03 12:29:11.148  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000024, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-03 12:29:11.162  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
04-03 12:29:11.162  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x40000025, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
04-03 12:29:11.170  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
04-03 12:29:11.170  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000026, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-03 12:29:11.176  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
04-03 12:29:11.176  26083-26087/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000027, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-03 12:29:11.715  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3D
04-03 12:29:12.295  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x47
04-03 12:29:12.464  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/asset﹕ AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
04-03 12:29:13.130  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
04-03 12:29:13.139  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ipower.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
04-03 12:29:13.140  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
04-03 12:29:13.141  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-03 12:29:13.142  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-03 12:29:13.143  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 12:29:13.143  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app I/System.out﹕ [CDS] fix other exception in HttpUrlConnection
04-03 12:29:13.143  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException
04-03 12:29:13.143  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:87)
04-03 12:29:13.143  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
04-03 12:29:13.143  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ipower.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
04-03 12:29:13.144  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 12:29:13.145  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-03 12:29:13.145  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-03 12:29:13.145  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-03 12:29:13.145  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 12:29:13.171  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app V/PhoneWindow﹕ DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4
04-03 12:29:14.790  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app V/PhoneWindow﹕ DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
04-03 12:29:14.919  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-03 12:29:14.936  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-03 12:29:14.941  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-03 12:29:15.013  26083-26083/com.example.ipower.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: What does the HTML you get look like ?

Comment: @JonasCz i added the html part , hope you help us

Comment: If you put `System.out.println(document);` in your code, what do you get ?

Comment: am using android studio

Comment: Output will show in the LogCat in android studio. Does it show the actual HTML you expect ?

Comment: nope ..i got nothing

Comment: Then your problem is that the server is not returning anything, and you should look into that. Do you see any Exceptions or Stack traces ?

Comment: 04-01 22:16:58.129  13780-13780/com.example.poweralert.app I/System.out﹕ [CDS] fix other exception in HttpUrlConnection

Comment: You should try to figure out why your jSoup document contains no HTML. Seems like there is a problem getting the document. Try setting the User Agent of jSoup to one a desktop browser would use and see what happens.

Comment: the same code is worked on eclipse..how can i solve the problem in android studio

Comment: Are you sure the code is run properly then ?

Comment: the code runs properly in eclipse and get the title from the url.But it doesn't work in android studio.when i put break points get the HtmlTree parsing i mentioned in the post

Comment: Strange. Do you have the correct imports at the top of the source file ? Post some more of your code and I might see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @JonasCz updated take a look , help me

Comment: Do you get any Exceptons / Stack Traces while _not_ debugging ? Try to put some `System.out.println(...)` calls in you code, and see what gets printed to LogCat. Try printing the title of the Document to LogCat. Does it show up ?

Comment: @JonasCz i updated the log cat in the question.Take a look please

Comment: You have an `IOException` somewhere in `onCreate()`, Do you have internet permission for your app ? Internet access on your device ?

Comment: How to give permission for the app ? kindly share the details

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2378619/4428462

Comment: same ...i could not get the title.I think some error in http connection have any idea about that

Comment: You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/4428462) for the fix. I will try out your ode later and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @JonasCz thank you i fixed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405761/android-parse-trouble-html-using-jsoup/29429872#29429872