# Android parse trouble HTML using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, android-studio, jsoup

we get trouble parsing live url using jsoup in android studio.the same code will be working in eclipse.we got the error

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.can not evaluate org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreebuilder.tostring()
```

here my activity code

```
String title=null;
    Document document;
    try {
        document= Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
        title=document.title();
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(title);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("tag","document");

    }
```

how to solve this issue and get the title from the live url?

Comment: Also based on comments from that question: are you sure that you are using same versions of jsoup in both android-studio and eclipse?

Comment: am using the same version of jsoup latest 1.8.1.help e to solve this issue

Comment: @Pshemo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390379/couldnt-parse-the-html-tags-from-live-site-in-android take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `AsyncTask` class to avoid `NetworkOnMainThreadException` 
here you can try this code.

```
private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String websiteTitle, websiteDescription;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to website
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            // Get the html document title
            websiteTitle = document.title();
            Elements description = document.select("meta[name=description]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            websiteDescription = description.attr("content");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtData);
        txttitle.setText(websiteTitle + "\n" + websiteDescription);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

and add your mainActivity this

```
new FetchWebsiteData().execute();
```

Comment: hope you get the answer