# Socket connection fail from Android

Tags: android, sockets

I have connected Android application to PC by Socket connection.
The code I used very simple like:

```
InetAddress hostIP = InetAddress.getByAddress(SERVER_IP);
Sender_Socket = new Socket(hostIP, SERVERPORT);
```

My `SERVER_IP` is: `"10.224.41.104"` hostIP is `10.-32.41.104`
and `IOException` occur when create new Socket with `hostIP`

How should I fix this problem? Thanks for all help ^^

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: @KovBal: the problem is IOException occur

Comment: Did you checked what happens with Wireshark or any other network diagnostics tool? It could be a firewall, etc.

Comment: What is the message associtated with the IOException?

Comment: @KovBal: I had developed by Xamarin (C#) and connection is OK. but when I use native with Android, this problem occur. so I don't think firewall... prevent the connection

Comment: @Dimitri: 08-06 17:05:20.729: E/APP(17446): java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2378619

Comment: @KovBal: Thank you very much! This fix my problem ^^

Comment: `SERVER_IP ` and `hostIP` are the SAME just represented in different dataType (InetAddress and a String) so there is no sense there IP value is NOT the same... you are mixing something or is it just a typo ?