# Unable to connect to external page in PhoneGap - network connection error

Tags: android, html, cordova, iframe

this is my frist post. First I have to say that I'm just a newbie and almost all parts of my HTML code was written by Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V method.

I'm trying to port my Symbian web widget application for my school to Android, Windows Phone and so on. I decided to use phonegap. Build goes ok via online service, but when i click to page, which contains External page), the app doesn't look like it is trying to connect anywhere.

1) Page using a href

```
<center>
<table border="4">
<tr><td><center><a href="http://m.youtube.com/channel/UCZLi2mLAjOITyxlPoY6vlXA/videos?itct=CAAQhGciEwjc6fqH7prKAhUF5hwKHf7BBvk"><img src="youtube.png" alt="loader" height="92" width="275" align="centre"><p>Kanál Daniela Borůvky</p></a></center></td></tr>
<tr><td><center><a href="http://m.facebook.com/PriznaniGjs"><img src="facebook.png" alt="loader" height="48" width="226" align="centre"><p>Přiznání GJŠ</p></a></center></td></tr>
<tr><td><center><a href="index2.html"><img src="back.png" width="64" height="64" alt="back" align="centre"><p>Zpět</p></a></center></td></tr>
</table>
</center>
```

2) Page using iframe

```
<center>
<div style="max-width:100%;overflow:auto;">
<iframe src="http://www.gjs.cz/" max-width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
<br>
</center>
<table border="4">
<tr><td><a href="choose.html"><center><img src="back.png" width="64" height="64"><br>Zpátky</center></a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested network permissions on Android? Unless you do, you program will get an error when it attempts to make network connections.

You can request internet access permission as outlined in the answer to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application).

About the comment: yes on the android.permission.INTERNET, no on android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, unless you need to know if the user is currently connected (as opposed to handling the error that results from trying to access the internet).

Comment: So I should add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> to my config.xml file?

Comment: I decompiled my app and found out that it already was in AndroidManifest.xml 
`    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />, ...`