# I am confused by android permission

Tags: android

I want to get the location from Android, so I set a permission. But I got confused when I found another article saying:

> android.permission.INTERNET is needed.

Why is it so? Does `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` include `INTERNET`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permission do I need to access Internet from an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INTERNET permission allows you to connect to the internet.  Without it, all attempts will fail or throw an exception.  FINE_LOCATION allows you to use GPS.  It does not include INTERNET.

Comment: Your app may need it for other reasons, but if you're using gps all you need is fine location. Note if you're using the fused location provide you may need internet to use AGPS

Comment: from Android Developer API, I just find two ways of getting location.And Permission_Fine_location is sufficient for both,including GPS and Internet.

Comment: ...that's what I said.  I also explained what INTERNET was, maybe that confused you?

Comment: I want to explain when you use Permission_FINE_LOCATION,you don't need to add INTERNET_PERMISSION. However thank you very much,this is my first time to ask for help