# How to get data with retrofit and save to database

Tags: android, retrofit2, activeandroid

I have an android app in which I need to get data from web api and save it into database.

I'm using retrofit to connect to web api and also I'm using active android.

So this is what I have created so far:

My table model "Partners", the data which I'm retrieving from web api and saving into this table Partners.

```
@Table(name = "Partners")
public class Partners extends Model {
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String name;
    public Partners() {}
    public List<Partners> getPartners() { return getMany(Partners.class, "Partners");}
}
```

I have created ApiService

```
public interface APIService {    
    @GET("Partners")
    Call<Partners> getPartners();
}
```

I have api helper

```
public class APIHelper {

    public static APIService apiService;

    public static APIService getApiService() {
        if (apiService == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://here-is-part-of-link/partners.json")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

An this is my fragment where I'm trying to invoke method to get data from web api.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements Callback<Partners> {

    Button shippingFragment, deliveryFragment, measurementFragment, takeOversFragment;
    private Call<Partners> call;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, parent, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Title");
        shippingFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shipping);
        deliveryFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delivery);
        measurementFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.measurement);
        takeOversFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.take_overs);
        shippingFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);
        deliveryFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);
        measurementFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);
        takeOversFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);

        call = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();
        call.enqueue(this);

        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnFragmentListener = (new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.shipping:
                    fragment = new ShippingFragment();
                    replaceFragment(fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.delivery:
                    fragment = new DeliveryMain();
                    replaceFragment(fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.measurement:
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MeasurementMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.take_overs:
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AllLogs.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    public void replaceFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment rFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, rFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    final Callback<List<Partners>> partnersCallback = new Callback<List<Partners>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Partners>> call, Response<List<Partners>> response) {
            for(Partners partners) {
                partners.save();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Partners>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    };
}
```

**QUESTION: I would be grateful if someone could tell me what I did wrong here and guide me into right direction??**

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong with this code

Comment: @cricket_007 the thing that is wrong is that this part of code breaks and wont save into table partners.

Comment: Please add the logcat or the compilation error message

Comment: @cricket_007 just added

Comment: Umm. Did you try to search for `"Missing INTERNET permission?"`

Comment: Duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application#2378619

Comment: This permission was there but somehow it has been deleted from my manifest.

Do you have any tips on how to save this data to my table Partners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Call variable expects a `Partners` object, but the Callback sees a `List<Partners>` (that's what is wrong, unless you actually do expect a JSON list),  meanwhile you have `implements Callback<Partners>`... So the types don't match.

Tip: To avoid confusion, rename your class to `Partner` since it's a single instance of *one* Partner

Answer (score 1):

You must add Internet Permission on your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three problems :

1. The callback and call variable do not correspond
2. If you see the documentation of retrofit2 you can see that the base url is concatenated with value of `GET` annotation so I think you url is `https://here-is-part-of-link/partners.json/Partners` when you call the `ApiService`
3. When retrofit gets the answer if it's good it will use `GSONConverter` (use in your helper) which will need setter to initialize your object. So try to add getter and setter to your `Parteners` object

Comment: I made Callback and Call variables corresponded. Also changed link when I'm calling ApiService. 
And still not working.   Still won't get all partners from web and also failed to save them into db (this part is also unclear to me). 
I'll post error log in question.