# Permissions webview android

Tags: android, webview

I'm new on this community and I hope you can help me. I'm trying to create a WebView app that contains a WebRTC. My problem, I suppose that is I have no idea how to request the web permissions in app. Maybe the problem is other. Anyway when I run the app I see this.

I want to make this "play" image disappear:

[image]

and show this thing that is the original webpage

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That image most likely means you have a <video> tag on the HTML of the webpage you're opening in your webview. If your webview loads an external url (from the internet) you only need the internet permission, otherwise no permission needed.

Comment: Ok. Could you explaint me a little how to remove or hide the <video> tag please

Comment: See my answer, I tried to elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your webview doesn't load an external page (from the internet) you don't need any permission, otherwise you only need the internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

That image means you probably have an HTML `<video>` tag on your HTML page, which is taking the whole screen (height - width), and which is declared as an auto-playing video, by default Android blocks Auto-playing videos.

Example:

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

So,

1- Make sure you use the `WebChromeClient`

2- Here's a method to initialize your webview:

```
@SuppressLint ("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void initWebview () {
    webview = findViewById (R.id.my_webview);

    webView.setWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient () {

        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage (ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            Log.e ("WebView - Logger", consoleMessage.messageLevel () + " : " + consoleMessage.lineNumber () + " : " + consoleMessage.message ());
            return true;
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings ();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort (true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode (true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode (WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}
```

3-

- If you wanna allow whatever HTML video in your pages to be played automatically (like probably in your case), without showing that big "Play" image add to your `initWebview` method: `webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture (false);`
- If you don't want to allow the autoplaying remove the `autoplay` attribute from the `<video>` tag in your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special permission to display a WebView. You just need the internet permission, to load that web page. For asking that see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application).