# Flutter: Not able to make HTTP-GET request

Tags: android, flutter

My code looks like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.get('192.168.4.1', 80, '/').then((HttpClientRequest req) {
    print(req.connectionInfo);
    return req.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse rsp) {
  print(rsp);
});
```

I'm trying to make a HTTP-Get request in the local wifi-network, that has no internet-connection, but I always get the following Error:

> E/flutter ( 8386): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>   E/flutter ( 8386): SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 192.168.4.1, port = 80
>   E/flutter ( 8386): #0      _rootHandleUncaughtError. (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
>   E/flutter ( 8386): #1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
>   E/flutter ( 8386): #2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)

I'm using an android device.

Comment: Is this in debug or release builds?

Comment: It's a debug build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application should be enabled by default for debug builds though

Comment: try restart emulator, there is a bug sometimes with connection on emulators. 
test on a webpage on your emulator

Comment: try to add http://192.168.4.1 instead only the ip

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flutter

I am able to make an http GET request from Flutter like this:

```
String androidEmulatorLocalhost = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000';
Response response = await get(androidEmulatorLocalhost);
String bodyText = response.body;
```

which requires `import 'package:http/http.dart';`.

## Server

Here is my [Node.js server](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) running locally:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

### See also

- [How to make HTTP requests in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641839/3681880)
- [Becoming a backend developer - Part 3: Connecting to the server from a mobile app](https://pusher.com/tutorials/backend-developer-part-3)

Comment: You don't have to refer to the proxy localhost IP address on the android emulator, instead you can just forward ("reverse") the port from the host machine to the android emulator. So if the server that your app needs to reach is running on localhost:3000, you can do `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000` in your terminal, and you should be able access the host server at localhost:3000 from your android emulator, and therefore be able to refer to that server with localhost:3000 from your Flutter app.