# HTTP request in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for Android. It is easy to retrieve and upload JSON via a REST based web service. Can we get any library which is equivalent to Retrofit for web services in Flutter?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio

Comment: Questions about external resources like tutorials, tools, libraries, ... are discouraged on StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help for more details (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Update

Originally I wrote the answer here first, but I ended up writing a more detailed post later:

- [How to make HTTP requests in Flutter](https://suragch.medium.com/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef)

The full source code is there, too.

### How to make HTTP requests in Flutter

This answer tells how to make HTTP requests using the [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) by the Dart team. If more advanced functionality is needed, check out the [Dio package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) mentioned in the comments.

We will be using [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) as a target for our API examples below.

```
GET     /posts
GET     /posts/1
GET     /posts/1/comments
GET     /comments?postId=1
GET     /posts?userId=1
POST    /posts
PUT     /posts/1
PATCH   /posts/1
DELETE  /posts/1
```

### Setup

Add the http package dependency in *pubspec.yaml*.

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+1
```

### GET requests

```
_makeGetRequest() async {

  // make request
  final response = await get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
  
  // sample info available in response
  final statusCode = response.statusCode;
  final headers = response.headers;
  final contentType = headers['content-type'];
  final json = response.body;

  // TODO convert json to object...

}
```

Replace `/posts` with `/posts/1` and the other GET requests mentioned above. Using `posts` returns an array of JSON objects while `/posts/1` returns a single JSON object. You can use [dart:convert](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-manually-using-dartconvert) to convert the raw JSON string to objects.

### POST request

```
_makePostRequest() async {
  
  // set up POST request arguments
  final url = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  final headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  final json = '{"title": "Hello", "body": "body text", "userId": 1}';

  // make POST request
  final response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);

  // check the status code for the result
  final statusCode = response.statusCode;
  
  // this API passes back the id of the new item added to the body
  final body = response.body;
  // {
  //   "title": "Hello",
  //   "body": "body text",
  //   "userId": 1,
  //   "id": 101
  // }

}
```

### PUT request

A PUT request is meant to replace a resource or create it if it doesn't exist.

```
_makePutRequest() async {

  // set up PUT request arguments
  final url = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  final headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  final json = '{"title": "Hello", "body": "body text", "userId": 1}';

  // make PUT request
  final response = await put(url, headers: headers, body: json);

  // check the status code for the result
  final statusCode = response.statusCode;

  // this API passes back the updated item with the id added
  final body = response.body;
  // {
  //   "title": "Hello",
  //   "body": "body text",
  //   "userId": 1,
  //   "id": 1
  // }

}
```

### PATCH request

A PATCH request is meant to modify a existing resource.

```
_makePatchRequest() async {

  // set up PATCH request arguments
  final url = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  final headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  final json = '{"title": "Hello"}';

  // make PATCH request
  final response = await patch(url, headers: headers, body: json);

  // check the status code for the result
  final statusCode = response.statusCode;

  // only the title is updated
  final body = response.body;
  // {
  //   "userId": 1,
  //   "id": 1
  //   "title": "Hello",
  //   "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae... (old body text not changed)",
  // }

}
```

Notice that the JSON string that is passed in only includes the title, not the other parts like in the PUT example.

### DELETE request

```
_makeDeleteRequest() async {

  // post 1
  final url = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');

  // make DELETE request
  final response = await delete(url);

  // check the status code for the result
  final statusCode = response.statusCode;

}
```

### Authentication

Although the demo site we used above did not require it, if you need to include authentication headers, you can do it like this:

Basic Authentication

```
// import 'dart:convert'

final username = 'username';
final password = 'password';
final credentials = '$username:$password';
final stringToBase64Url = utf8.fuse(base64Url);
final encodedCredentials = stringToBase64Url.encode(credentials);

final headers = {
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", // or whatever
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic $encodedCredentials",
};
```

Bearer (token) Authentication

```
// import 'dart:io';

final token = 'WIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6Ikpv';

final headers = {
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", // or whatever
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
};
```

### Related

- [What is the difference between PUT, POST and PATCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch)

Answer (score 1):

Well for me at least you will need 3 packages.

1. [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)
2. [Dio Http Client](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)
3. [retrofit for dart](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit)

I have tried chopper but I prefer the dio way of doing things. it is closer and more flexible.

Comment: no need to implement dio, retrofit has it implemented

Answer (score 0):

get to the location of pubspac.yaml run cmd

```
> flutter pub get 
> flutter packages get
```

add

> http: ^0.11.3+16

in **pubspac.yaml**

get dependencies.
try to import library, hopes this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Just simple use this plug and little code for `GET` http url

add this plugin from here [httppackage](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
 http: ^0.12.0+2
```

**USAGE**

```
final uri = Constants.BASE_URL + 'endpoint';
    final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};//if required
    Response getResponse = await get(uri, headers: headers);
    int statusCode = getResponse.statusCode;
    String responseBody = getResponse.body;
    print('response----' + responseBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to android we do have a flutter retrofit package https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit

but in flutter [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package used very widely.

To use this

Add dependency to **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.1
```

**Note:** Always use latest dependency

---

**Usage:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  print("main Method");
  String url =
      "https://5f383e6541c94900169bfd42.mockapi.io/api/v1/user_details";
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  print(response.body);
}
```

This package provides easy options to add headers and body while get/post data