# Where did IOClient go in the Dart http package?

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I'm working on making http requests from a Flutter project. I have seen several answers refer to `IOClient`. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897486/3681880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848252/3681880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422793/3681880). However, the following imports do not work (though they apparently used to):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show IOClient;
```

Instead, the second one gives the error message:

> The library 'package:http/http.dart' doesn't export a member with the shown name 'IOClient'.

How do I import IOClient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`IOClient`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/io_client/IOClient-class.html) is still in the [`http` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) but it is no longer in the [`http` library](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/http-library.html). It has been extracted into its own library as [`io_client`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/io_client/io_client-library.html). You can import it like this:

```
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
```