# How to make api call of string in flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter. This is the string that I need to call and I don't know how to call this type of string.

```
{
   "Info":[
      {
         "c_type_id":"1",
         "cleaning type":"Washroom Cleaning"
      },
      {
         "c_type_id":"2",
         "cleaning type":"Garden\/Lawn Cleaning"
      }
   ]
}
```

My code

```
  class Album {
    final String title;
     Album({
      this.title,
     });
     factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       return Album(
       title: json['title'],
      );
     }
    }
```

As I am following my code like this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
and got this error "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget." because they are following this type of string and my string type is different. Help!

```
{
 "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your given data (API response) seems to have a list of maps, so you should get the data first (use async function):

```
var response = await http.get("Your Url")
```

then you should extract the given map list as follow:

```
var temp = json.decode(response);
List<dynamic> result = temp['Info']); // it is the described list
```

now, you can use your data (extract each parameter):

```
String c_type_id = result[0]['c_type_id'];
// and so on...
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but where to add 
var temp = json.decode(response);
List<dynamic> result = temp['Info']);

Comment: you can use these commands in the "then" function! as you maybe know, http.get is an async function and after getting the result, you can call .then function!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear at all but I can show you an example how to reach an element in a json.
Your json consists a list that contains string keys. To reach first element of list;

```
json["Info"][0]
```

Then pass the key you want to get its value;

```
json["Info"][0]["c_type_id"]
```

[http_requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360761/http-request-in-flutter) All type of http requests are mentioned in this post. If you have any further problem kindly make comment.

Comment: i used your method like this
class Album {
  final String title;
  final String id;

  Album({
    this.title,
    this.id,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      title: json['Info'][0],
      id: json["Info"][0]["c_type_id"],
    );
  }
}
and this is showing this message on screen "type 'internalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not subtype of 'String'"  :( where I am wrong

Comment: you can not use { title: json['Info'][0] } like this. When you get this property it inclueds a list includes a map.  json['Info'][0] = [{"c_type_id":"1","cleaning type":"WashroomCleaning"}, {"c_type_id":"2","cleaning type":"Garden\/Lawn Cleaning"}]. This is not a string