# Bing Autosuggest api for an android app,but it give Response code as 404 and Resource not found,but the same code is working fine in a java compiler

Tags: java, android, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I want to use Bing Autosuggest API in an android app. I used the documented code from here :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Bing-Autosuggest/quickstarts/java
The code is working fine when run/compiled the same code in a simple java compiler :-https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler

My app is able to open the url https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/Suggestions/?subscription-Key=my_key&q=india in a web-view(which means there is no internet problem in the app). Android need to call this in a separate thread, thats why I used Async, here.

For the below code, First Url is working fine(200 as response code), but Second one gives Response code as 404.

And both can be open in a browser with their exact url link

```
    url = new URL("https://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=abcd");
    url = new URL("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/Suggestions/?mkt=en-IN&subscription-Key=key&q=india");

    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    int HttpsREsult = connection.getResponseCode();
```

As mentioned in the documentation, I have written the code as follow:-

In Android the code is written as below:-

```
 public class bing_ac_main extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    protected String subscriptionKey = "my key";  
    protected String host = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
    protected String path = "/bing/v7.0/Suggestions";
    protected String mkt = "en-IN";
    protected String query = "sail";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String encoded_query = null;
        try {
            encoded_query = URLEncoder.encode (query, "UTF-8");
            String params = "?mkt=" + mkt + "&q=" + encoded_query;

            URL url = new URL (host + path + params);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            int HttpsREsult = connection.getResponseCode();
            String Httpsstring= connection.getResponseMessage();
      .......
```

In the online compiler I have written the same code in a function as:-

```
    public  static String getResponse(){

        String subscriptionKey = "my key";  
        String host = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
        String path = "/bing/v7.0/Suggestions";
        String mkt = "en-IN";
        String query = "ind";

        String encoded_query = null;
        try {
            encoded_query = URLEncoder.encode (query, "UTF-8");
            String params = "?mkt=" + mkt + "&q=" + encoded_query;

            URL url = new URL (host + path + params);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            int HttpsREsult = connection.getResponseCode();
     .....
}
```

I expected the HttpsResult should be 200, but the actual output is 404 in android.
I am getting HttpsResult as 200 in the online compiler for the same code, which is correct

Comment: Android apps need a [permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application/2378619) to access internet.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen, I have already written the permission in Manifest file, and the internet is working fine in the sample app.