# Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform

Tags: flutter, http, connection

I am facing following issue :
I/flutter (31349): Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://max-image-caption-generator-test.2886795296-80-host19nc.environments.katacoda.com/model/predict

I added following lines in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
</application>
```

But still I am facing the error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTTP connections are not allowed anymore since Flutter 2.0 on Android and iOS.
There are two solutions: You can use only HTTPS connections or you can activate unsecure connections (e.g. for debugging). The following article describes how to do this: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android or [Flutter Insecure http is not allowed by platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172791/flutter-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take permission to use http

For Android -> `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `application` in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
  ...
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

For IOS -> add below lines in Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```