# How to connect to Localhost?

Tags: flutter, authentication, localhost, local, host

I'm here new, I'm learning flutter and I need login with this:
POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/session

But I still can't login :( I'm waiting 5 minutes and still there is a loading screen with no effects.

I have try

So I have have made a this api_service with this tutorial made https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Kw4BfNX1-4

here is my api_service.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../model/login_model.dart';

class APIService {
Future<LoginResponseModel> 
login(LoginRequestModel requestModel) async {
String url = "http://localhost:3000/api/users/session";

final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());
if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 400) {
  return LoginResponseModel.fromJson(
    json.decode(response.body),
  );
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
}
}
}
```

Here is debug console:

> E/flutter (10967): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused,
> errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 58856 E/flutter (10967):
>
> I'm try with this page:
> https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130
>
> I change String url = "http://localhost:3000/api/users/session"; to
> String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/users/session";
>
> in my debug console i have completely different messages, but stilll
> don't work :(
>
> E/flutter (10967):
>
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
>
> Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by
> platform: http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/users/session
>
> E/flutter (10967): #0      _HttpClient._openUrl
> (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2434:7)
>
> E/flutter (10967): #1      _HttpClient.openUrl
> (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2341:7)
>
> E/flutter (10967): #2      IOClient.send
> package:http/src/io_client.dart:31
>
> (...) to #28 and the last ist E/flutter (10967):

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Insecure http is not allowed by platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172791/flutter-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform)

Comment: Are you on Android Emulator? If yes, change `http://localhost:3000/api/users/session` by `http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/users/session`

Comment: Hello, yes, i'm on Android Emulator. I'm have tried with http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/users/session but this don't work.
With https://10.0.2.2:3000/api/users/session and this don't work too :/

Answer (score 1):

**Fix for the Error Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform**

Flutter terms **http** as an insecure source Therefore you should either use **https** or set **android:usesCleartextTraffic** to true in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
                android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
                android:label="receipt"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" // Add this line
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```