# I need help for this eroor in flutter http and I dont know what i do

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

this is my code and I don't know whats my problem :( please help me

[image]

Comment: Try using https instead of http

Comment: Check out this: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172791/flutter-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform#answer-65730723

Comment: @Muhtar i did , this is my result

Comment: @Muhtar check run : https://file.io/5r5I6eoFJ3nx

Answer (score 1):

The system default does not allow insecure connections. If you want to use an insecure connection, follow the steps below.

For Android;
Go main manifest.xml file (android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml)
Add the following line between the 'application' tags.

```xml
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

For iOS;
Go info.plist file (ios->Runner->Info.plist)
Add the following line between the 'dict' tags.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```