# Disabling Verify SSL Certificate in flutter web

Tags: flutter, ssl, flutter-web

I use flutter to build a web application. When I send a request to my localhost server IP address, or send a request to a host without `HTTPS` (SSL Certificate), I got `XMLHttpRequest error`. I searched about that and any user says to add `CORS` on the server-side and add some headers to request and server, But my server and request have that. I think `XMLHttpRequest error` is for the SSL Certificate of my host. In mobile, we can use some library like [restio](https://pub.dev/packages/restio) and add `verifySSLCertificate: false` to request and ignore that. But I don't know how to send requests without error in flutter web. Can you help me?

My code for send a simple request and got that error:

```
var client = http.Client();
String theUrl = 'http://192.168.1.9/index.php/get_items';
var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(theUrl));
print(response.body);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172791/flutter-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform

Comment: @rstrelba this is not a solution for flutter web

Comment: @MarlenSchreiner do you have any idea how to fix this?