connect the local api to the device handphone
when running on the device the display does not appear

I/flutter (18296): Error: ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 44450, uri=http://localhost/api_projek/coba_api.php

var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost/api_projek/coba_api.php'));


Does this answer your question? Accessing localhost API from android device

If you're using a an android emulator, they cannot access localhost, use 10.0.2.2 instead. So the new URL would be 'http://10.0.2.2/api_projek/coba_api.php'.
If you're using a physical device, you can use ngrok to temporarily put your local API online

If you're using Android, because you're using HTTP and not HTTPS, you'll need to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to your androidmanifest.xml file as stated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172791/flutter-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform
