# I wanted to get the content(HTML) from website and while running the app i am getting this run time error, and i am not able to resolve this

Tags: java, android

**I wanted to get the content(HTML) from website and while running the app i am getting this run time error, and i am not able to resolve this.**

**Main Activity**
This is my java code to read data from website and log the result in LOGCAT window,I have tried various solution for this even is re download my android studio.

```
package com.example.demo;

import **androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity**;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;
        try {
            //sending utl to class method doInBackground()
            result = task.execute("http://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk").get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Result", result);
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**error**
This is the error popped up on my LOGCAT window and i don't know how to resolve this.

```
2021-04-28 23:23:35.339 8332-8332/? I/om.example.dem: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-04-28 23:23:35.372 8332-8332/? E/om.example.dem: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2021-04-28 23:23:35.457 8332-8332/com.example.demo I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2021-04-28 23:23:35.473 8332-8359/com.example.demo E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.demo
2021-04-28 23:23:35.473 8332-8359/com.example.demo E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-04-28 23:23:35.474 8332-8359/com.example.demo E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.demo
2021-04-28 23:23:35.474 8332-8359/com.example.demo E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-04-28 23:23:35.474 8332-8359/com.example.demo E/Perf: Fail to get file list oat
2021-04-28 23:23:35.474 8332-8359/com.example.demo E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: You might want to revisit the title of your Question

Comment: Your have internet permission? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)

Comment: Yes! I updated my manifest file for that