# How to run python code with socket library with root access in Android app

Tags: python, android-studio, kivy, google-colaboratory, chaquopy

I have created a port scanner in Python which uses "socket" library. I want to implement that in an Android app. I'll Explain the things i've done :

1. Used "Chaquopy" Library to run the code, it ran successfully but won't be able to find any port. and error was "Operation Not Permitted" ( i researched a bit and it says it's because root access is not given
2. Trying to Use kivy library for this (but still have no idea if it'll work on not)
3. i was thinking if there's any way to use google colab for compiling the program( because i used it to run the code and it works perfectly and fast)

I want to find a way to run the app with root access so everything works perfectly

that's everything i've done.
please provide some suggestion and advice
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is making TCP or UDP connections, and you're not attempting to use a local port number below 1024, then you won't need root access. However, you will need the [INTERNET permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607).