# How to solve "Socket error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out" in Chaquopy Android-kotlin

Tags: python, android, kotlin, sockets

Recently I've been working on **Chaquopy**, Android-Python Library and my aim is to build a **Port Scanner** in android.

Code for **Port Scanner Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.chaquo.python.PyObject
import com.chaquo.python.Python
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform
import com.example.happlication.R
import com.example.happlication.adapter.servicesAdapter
import com.example.happlication.databinding.ActivityPortScannerBinding
import com.example.happlication.servicesModel
import java.util.*

class PortScannerActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    lateinit var binding: ActivityPortScannerBinding
    lateinit var activity: Activity
    lateinit var scanoutput: PyObject
    lateinit var pyObj: PyObject
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_port_scanner)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_port_scanner)

        initView()
        onClick()


    }

    private fun initView()
    {
        activity = this
        window.statusBarColor = this.resources.getColor(R.color.black)
    }

    private fun onClick()
    {
        binding.ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.edtIpaddress.text.toString().isNotEmpty())
            {
                if (binding.edtPortnumber.text.toString().isNotEmpty())
                {
                    callScanner(this).execute()
                    binding.btnSearch.hideKeyboard()
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Enter the port number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Enter the IP address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }


    inner class callScanner(private var activity: PortScannerActivity?) : AsyncTask<String, String, String>()
    {

        override fun onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute()
            binding.loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        var result=""
        var error=""
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String
        {
            try
            {
                if (! Python.isStarted()) {
                    Python.start(AndroidPlatform(this@PortScannerActivity))
                }
                var ipaddress=binding.edtIpaddress.text.toString()
                var portnumber=binding.edtPortnumber.text.toString()
                var py=Python.getInstance()
                pyObj = py.getModule("portscanning")
                scanoutput=pyObj.callAttr("portScanner",ipaddress, portnumber.toInt())
                result=scanoutput.toString()
                return result
            }
            catch (e: Exception)
            {
                error=e.toString()
            }


         return "false"

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            binding.loading.visibility = View.GONE

            if (error.isNotEmpty())
            {
                binding.llErrorsection.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvError.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvError.text=error.toString()
            }
            else if (result.toString().isNotEmpty())
            {
                binding.llDetails.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvOuput.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvFinalOutput.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvFinalOutput.text=result.toString()
            }

        }
    }


    fun View.hideKeyboard() {
        val inputManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    }

}
```

Python file: **portscanning.py**

```
# importing the sockets module
import socket
def portScanner(target, port):
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    t_ip=socket.gethostbyname(target)
    print(f"starting scan on host {t_ip} with portnumber {port}")

    try:
        s.connect((t_ip, port))
        a=(f"port {port} is open")
        return a
    except Exception as e:
        b=(f"port {port} is closed")
        print(e)
        return b
```

The Error I got:
[image: Error]

Now if I run this Python file in normal **windows-python interpreter** then everything works fine
[image: output]

So is there some kind of permission I need to provide to this application, just like internet
OR some thing  like that ??

OR is it having some other solution, Please let me know
Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: Your app will need the [INTERNET permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2378607).

Comment: @mhsmith, I've already provided Internet permission in manifest file but it seems like there is some other problem, I'm still searching, Thanks for your answer though