# "Failed to start a local web server" while trying to stablish connection with Google Drive using PyDrive with Chaquopy plugin in an android app

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, pydrive, chaquopy

I am trying to upload a file from a moblie phone to Google Drive, inside my android app. Basically Chaquopy is a plugin that enables me to run python scripts inside an android application and I use it to take advantage from PyDrive library and upload the file I want. But before that, I am just trying to stablish a connection with Google Drive but it refuses to retrieve the code from authorized redirect URI http://localhost:8080/ (that is how I configured my web application`s credential on google cloud project). I've already tried to transfer a file from pc to google drive with this project (and method) and it worked fine.

I've also tried to break `gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()` in steps as suggested in [PyDrive documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#building-your-own-authentication-flow) but get no code at the end of authentication (can't connect to localhost).

I would like to use this method to upload the file, but other methods may be considered too.

my build.gradle (app level)

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.epshape"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"
            version "3.8"
            pip {
                install "pydrive"
            }
        }
    }
```

my python script:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
import os


def upload_dataset():
    GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = os.environ['HOME']+'/client_secrets.json'
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

python script call from java activity class:

```
public void onClickUploadDataset(View view) {
        Python py = Python.getInstance();
        PyObject module = py.getModule("upload_dataset");
        module.callAttr("upload_dataset");
    }
```

error:

```
2023-11-12 23:05:37.636 32523-32523 python.stdout           com.example.epshape                  I  Failed to start a local web server. Please check your firewall
2023-11-12 23:05:37.636 32523-32523 python.stdout           com.example.epshape                  I  settings and locally running programs that may be blocking or
2023-11-12 23:05:37.636 32523-32523 python.stdout           com.example.epshape                  I  using configured ports. Default ports are 8080 and 8090.
2023-11-12 23:05:37.648 32523-32523 AndroidRuntime          com.example.epshape                  D  Shutting down VM
2023-11-12 23:05:37.650 32523-32523 AndroidRuntime          com.example.epshape                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.epshape, PID: 32523
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160) 
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AuthenticationError: 
                                                                                                        at <python>.pydrive.auth.LocalWebserverAuth(auth.py:224)
                                                                                                        at <python>.pydrive.auth._decorated(auth.py:115)
                                                                                                        at <python>.upload_dataset.upload_dataset(upload_dataset.py:8)
                                                                                                        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:354)
                                                                                                        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:326)
                                                                                                        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)
                                                                                                        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)
                                                                                                        at com.example.epshape.MainActivity.onClickUploadDataset(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160) 
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your Android app runs on your Android device and you want to upload a file to Google Drive. This drive is on the internet. In this context i donr understand why you talk about `http://localhost:8080/`. Or why you mention your pc.

Comment: I mentioned the pc just to say that I already tested the python script and it works. The `http://localhost:8080/` is the address PyDrive documentation recommends to put when creating the credentials.

Comment: It still is unclear to me.  Is your Android app using `http://localhost:8080/` somewhere? As localhost would be the Android device itself. Not your pc.

Comment: `"Failed to start a local web server"` Unclear too. What kind of webserver? And where would it run locally? On your Android device or on your PC?

Comment: I think the pc part made it more confusing, we can forget about it, the app runs by itself without the need to connect to a pc. The address `http://localhost:8080/` comes from the configuration of google cloud project, I put it in [google cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/) > APIs & Services > Credentials > OAuth 2.0 Client IDs > Web Client > Authorized redirect URIs. This is what PyDrive documentation tells to do.

Comment: I asked if your Android app uses that url. You did not answer that with yes or no. And is there a web server running on your Android device?

Comment: YES and YES. As far as I know it does use the url when calling `gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()` and it runs a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using another solution. I upload the file through a service account plus a shared folder in google drive. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tamT_iGoZDQ) helped. I still run the python script with Chaquopy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your app has the [INTERNET permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2378607).

If that isn't it, the port 8080 may already be used by something else, so try some different values.

Comment: Thanks @mhsmith! I've ended up using another solution: a python script reaching google drive by a service account.