# Flutter app working when running in release mode but showing white screen when uploded to play store

Tags: flutter, release

when I run my app on a pixel 6a (real device) using flutter run --release everything is working fine and there an no errors.

When uploading it (flutter build appbundle --release) to the google console, downloading the "singned,universal APK" from the App bundle and test it on the same device the app opnes with a white screen and that's it.

I have read a lot about the white screen probem and I have upgraded gradle to the latest version, accepted the android license, .... but nothing helped.

Any hints what the problem could be?

Flutter doctor:

C:\SDKs\flutter_latest\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086], locale de-DE)
• Flutter version 3.16.6 on channel stable at C:\SDKs\flutter_latest\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 46787ee49c (2 days ago), 2024-01-09 14:36:07 -0800
• Engine revision 3f3e560236
• Dart version 3.2.3
• DevTools version 2.28.4

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.5)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.31229.75
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.3)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3
• Flutter plugin version 77.0.1
• Dart plugin version 233.13135.65

[√] Connected device (4 available)
• Pixel 6a (mobile) • 28291JEGR03200 • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34)
• Windows (desktop) • windows        • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome         • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.201
• Edge (web)        • edge           • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.121

[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading the "signed, universal APK" from the App bundle"? If you have created a new release on Google Play, are you installing it directly from the Play Store?

Comment: You should also enable Crashlytics to see if there is any runtime crash on the live version.

Comment: The version is not live and it is not accepted by google as it is "not responsive". To see the problem I upload the bundle and after uploading it I can see the bundle and download the "signed, universal APK" (translated from german)

Comment: This happened to me the other day. I use firebase as a backend and use firebase auth and firestore. When user signs in I do the auth stuff but I didn't have some settings/code correct to make the user profile doc, and when I navigated to the profile page it would be white. Not sure if it's something related to your backend, could you give some more details?

Comment: Have you added [internet permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2378619/13625293)?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Yes...they are added

Comment: When running local on a real device eyerything works and I now see:


E/AndroidRuntime(16167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16167): Process: com.samsung.accessory.fridaymgr, PID: 16167
E/AndroidRuntime(16167): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.samsung.accessory.fridaymgr.ApplicationClass: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.samsung.accessory.fridaymgr/oreocompat.I
nstantForegroundService
....

but the app runs as expected

Comment: Caused by: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.samsung.accessory.fridaymgr/oreocompat.InstantForegroundService